# How to copy formatted text from OneNote to other programs?

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-onenote, text-formatting, plaintext

The only way to not be pasted as image is to copy it as plain text. But I have an article with a lot of simple formatting (bold, italic, underline, table, indent) in various locations and would like to paste it into GMail. Having to reformat it is really burdensome. Is there a way to not having to paste it as plain text, but still get a non-image result?

Comment: it just works for me, I can copy text with formatting from OneNote (2013) to Gmail (in latest version of Chrome) under Windows 10, maybe share a bit more details to let us better understand your issue.

Comment: Might be pain to do that for a lot of different articles, but have you tried to go over Word? So Copy from OneNote > Word > Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour was new to me, even though I've been using both gmail and onenote for years.

I have a workaround suggestion: But might not be the simplest/prettiest solution: paste it into word, then copy --> paste to gmail --> appears as text with formatting.

Comment: It's weird that only Word can handle this, Libre Writer can't

Comment: Also only works from the App - it does not fully work when copying from the browser view.